# Click anywhere and type text, and then edit it, by clicking on it

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm working with kineticJS framework, and i want to make tool, which lets you click anywhere and type text, and if you click on already existing text, it will let you edit that text realtime. (same functionality like in word, as TextBox). Also i'll need to make that text subscript/superscript and etc. in future. I have no idea, how to make text editable realtime using keyboard. I know there is Text element in kineticjs, but that doesn't help me, because as far as i know you can't edit it in realtime (when clicking keyboard buttons). Also this should work on tablet devices. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Long story short:

- Using:

  - KineticJS(Canvas)
- Need:

  - Clicking anywhere places marker, which adds letters when i'm typing using keyboard, or tablet keyboard.
  - Clicking on already existing text, will place marker there and let me edit that text.
  - In future, i should have ability to set these features to that text:

    - set color
    - change font
    - add subscript/superscript
    - bold/underline/italic

Work in progress can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/66UcL/1/

CodeJS:

```
console.clear();
var containerID = "kiCanvas";
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: containerID,
    width: 600,
    height: 500,
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
$('#drawText').on('click', function () {
    $('canvas').on('click', drawText);
});

function drawText(e) {
    var newText = new Kinetic.Text({
        text: "Text",
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
        fill: 'red',
    });
    layer.add(newText);
    layer.draw();
}
```

CodeHTML:

```
<button id="drawText">AddTextToCanvas</button>
<div id="kiCanvas" />
```

TODO:

- Add cursor where you click, not full text.
- Let you edit text, when you click on it.

EDIT:

I've found a way, with input, which has 0 opacity, and which has event onKeyUp, updates text object in canvas, i'll upload sample, when it will be ready for public.

Comment: you're asking WAY too much to expect a useful answer.

Comment: i'll need at least something which will help my thinking, so i could find/code answer by myself and share with others.

Comment: That's not how SO works. You are expected to do your own preliminary research and attempt solutions then post specific questions about specific issues in your attempted solution(s). Your question only lists a set of requirements.

Comment: ok, thanks i'll edit my post, with research soon.

Comment: @JuliusR: Thanks for the updates.  I'm curious to know whether it's even possible for a `<canvas>` element to receive keyboard input on iOS.  Please continue to keep us informed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a similar tool-plugin of kineticJS that allows editing of Text directly on canvas.

It does what you require but does not include the additional features (subscript, underline, etc).

Take a look so you can get inspiration for your own tool or use it as is:

https://github.com/nktsitas/kineticjs-editable-text